# How to force NSTokenField to *move* tokens when dragging to another field?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, nstokenfield

The default drag operation when dragging a token from one `NSTokenField` and dropping it into another field is `NSDragOperationCopy`. Holding down the Command key when performing the drag changes the operation to `NSDragOperationMove`.

**How can I reverse this default behavior so that the tokens are moved by default, and copied only when holding down the Option key?**

I'm trying to imitate the behavior from the compose window in Mail where dragging an email token from the To field to the Cc field moves the token by default, and copies it when holding the Option key.

I have tried subclassing `NSTokenField` and overriding the `draggingEntered:` to return `NSDragOperationMove` but that does not seem to work.

---

Update:

I've ended up swizzling the `dragOperationForDraggingInfo:type:` method on `NSTextView` and returning `NSDragOperationMove` in the implementation by default. I also check if the option key is down and return `NSDragOperationCopy` if true. This seems to be working as expected for now, but I'm not sure if method swizzling is the best way to go here.

Comment: Is `draggingEntered:` called? What is `[sender draggingSourceOperationMask]`?

Comment: Yes, if I override `draggingEntered` on the NSTokenField subclass it is called when the dragged token enters the destination field. `[sender draggingSourceOperationMask]` is weirdly set to a raw value of 5.

Comment: `5` is `NSDragOperationCopy | NSDragOperationGeneric`.

Comment: Aah I see. But how can I change this to `NSDragOperationMove` as the default operation? The `draggingSourceOperationMask` property on sender is read-only so can't change it there. Logging `[sender draggingSource]` says it is an `NSTokenTextView` but that is not public so I cannot replace it or extend it.

Comment: If you don't mind using an undocumented feature then subclass `NSTokenField` and implement `textView:dragOperationForDraggingInfo:type:`.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Do you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Willeke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244136/willeke)'s comment, I got this to work by subclassing `NSTokenField` and implementing the undocumented `NSTextViewDelegate` method `textView:dragOperationForDraggingInfo:type:`.

Here's the exact code I used in my `NSTokenField` subclass:

```
class TokenField: NSTokenField { 
   
    @objc func textView(_ textView: NSTextView, dragOperationForDraggingInfo dragInfo: NSDraggingInfo, type: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType) -> NSDragOperation {

      // if option is pressed, always return .copy
      if NSApp.currentEvent?.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask) == .option {
        return .copy
      }

      // if the source and destination are the same, we want default NSTokenField behavior
      if let source = dragInfo.draggingSource as? NSTextView, textView == source {
        return .generic
      }

      // default to .move
      return .move
    }

}
```